# Plot multiple lines and scatter points on the same chart using d3, and use the mouseover function to calculate distance

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to plot multiple lines and scatter plot on the same d3 chart.And I also define a mouse over function to calculate the distance between the scatter points and the line. Here is my js code:

```
import measurement from '../datasets/measurement';

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%e/%_m/%Y %H");

// Get the data
d3.csv("../datasets/Book1.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.date = parseDate.parse(d.dateHour);
        d.estPressure = +d.x_inf;
        d.lowPressure = +d.m1std;
        d.upPressure = +d.p1std;
    });
console.log(data);

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 20, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 66},
    body_width = parseInt(d3.select('body').style('width').replace('px','')),
    width = body_width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 1000 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([parseDate.parse("1/5/2016 00"), parseDate.parse("14/5/2016 23")])
      //  .domain(data.date])
        .nice(d3.time.week)
        /*.domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.date;
        }))*/
        .range([0, width]);
    //.rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%B %e %H:00'));
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", 1780)
        .attr("y", 940)// text label for the x axis
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Time");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("pressure");

    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.upPressure;
    })]);


    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.estPressure);
        });


    // Draw line.
    var linegraph = svg.selectAll("path.line").data([data], function (d) {
        return d.date;
    });

    linegraph.attr('d', line).style("opacity", 1.0);

    linegraph.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);
});


var data1 = measurement.map(function (d) {
    Object.keys(d).forEach(function (key) {
        d[key] = +d[key];
    });
    return d;
});
console.log(data1);

// Add the scatterplot
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data1)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
        return x(d.t);
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return y(d.est);
    })
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {                                    //hover event
        tooltip.transition()
            .duration(100)
            .style("opacity", .9)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 20) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px");
        var dist = 0, lowerbound;
        data.forEach(function (n) {
            if (n.t === d.t) {
                dist = d.est - n.pressure ;
                if (dist < 0) dist = dist * -1;
            }
            else if (n.time < d.t) {                                          // linear interpolation for the t
                lowerbound = n;
            }
        });

        tooltip.html("<h1>" + "X: " + d.t + " Y: " + d.x + " distance:" + dist.toFixed(3) + "</h1>");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
        tooltip.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 0);
    });
```

And my csv data for the line chart is like this:

```
tHour,x_inf,p1std,m1std,dateHour
1,10,10.3,9.2,1/5/2016 00
2,12,16.8,7.2,1/5/2016 01
3,14,21.2,6.8,1/5/2016 02
4,15,19.8,10.2,1/5/2016 03
5,14.5,16.9,12.1,1/5/2016 04
6,18,22.96,13.04,1/5/2016 05
```

My jason data for the scatter points are like(measurement):

```
{
        "t": 1,
        "est": 1
    },
    {
        "t": 3,
        "est": 12
    },
    {
        "t": 5,
        "est": 14
    },
    {
```

Could anyone help me about the code? I am new to d3...And I just can plot only one line here using the dateHour as x and x_inf as y in the csv data. I want to use dateHour data as x and plot three lines using  x_inf,p1std,m1std values. It would be so nice if you could also help me with the scatter points.

Comment: I seem to figure out how to plot multiple lines. But the scatter points still not showing, and i am struggling with how to define the distance function....

Comment: First, your AJAX in your CSV data, and in the callback, your create the variables needed for your scatter plot.  But the CSV callback is async while the scatter plot is not, so those variables are not created yet.  Second, in your scatter plot you are using the `x` which is expecting a datetime, on your measurement data of integers.  That's just not going to work.  Here's a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zTGUvIuchoHs8cg72VHv?p=preview) where I've started to wade through your problems, but with the data inconsistency I can't go any further....

Comment: Thanks for your useful advice, Mark~~